# how to include a file in nodejs that is not a module?

Tags: node.js

I just want to include some params from an external file into my nodejs script.

Same as in php `<?php include("sql.php"); ?>`

That means: not a module, but simply an inclusion of file

Any idea ?

Comment: Idea? Yeah: load file, `eval` file's content. However, I ___really___ hope that there is a better way. (And this solution doesn't do exactly the same as you want)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting your params into a JSON file will work fine.

### params.json

```
{"foo": "bar"}
```

### myscript.js

```
var params = require('./params');
console.log(params.foo);
```

But otherwise CommonJS modules are your mechanism in node. If you are asking this question, you aren't ready to use `eval` safely, so don't go there.